# What happens when Redis stream data reach memory limit?

Tags: redis

https://redis.io/topics/streams-intro doesn't make it clear to me what happens when Redis stream data reach the memory limit.

In other words, is it the user's responsibility (burden) to ensure stream data volume stay within the memory limit and do the pruning when necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis stream is nothing special, but just another data structure. So when reaching the memory limit, you can control the behavior with the `maxmemory` and `maxmemory-policy` configuration. Check `redis.conf` file for details on these two configs.